# I need to send html element supported e-mail message which contains dynamically builded string body

Tags: html, asp.net, email, exception, c#-4.0

i have this code which generates a log or report about exception and it uses string builder type variable to which exception's properties and values are appended which gets that by using exceptions object.so now when i call the send email method by putting string builder variable into the arguement the message body gets what's in this variable.So here i want my code to insert html elements like  and  in this message body of the mail to add some styling.To which i'm not getting any idea how to accomplish this,i simply need to write the exception property as bold and set the font family of the property and value to be different in the mail body.Please help me with this!

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class EnterMarks : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public float average,total;
       public string grade,chk,exmessage;

       DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            
           
        }

      

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
           
             tblExcDet te = new tblExcDet();
            var query1 = from n in db.tblContacts select n.StudentID;
           

                foreach (var q in query1)
                {
                    if (q.Equals((int.Parse(TextBox4.Text))))
                    {
                        Label2.Text = "ID Found";
                    }
                }
                try
                {


                    int? i = null;
                    tblContact tc = new tblContact();
                    tc.StudentID = (int)i ;
                    //db.tblContacts.InsertOnSubmit(tc);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   
                    
                    log(ex);
                    Label2.Text = "Can't assign null value into a table id";
                   
                }
                        
        }
       
        public static void log(Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sbEMessage = new StringBuilder();
            DateTime mydatetime1 = DateTime.Now;
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Message" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Date and Time" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(mydatetime1 + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Source" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.Source + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Hresult" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.HResult + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Stack trace" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Data" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.Data + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception target site" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Inner Exception");
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.InnerException + Environment.NewLine);
            sendEmail(sbEMessage.ToString());
        }
        public static void sendEmail(string emailbody)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("kamal.enest@gmail.com", "kamalu960@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Exception";
            mailMessage.Body = emailbody;
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "kamal.enest@gmail.com",
                Password = "1011664123"
            };
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add html tags like bold, italic, table structure, need to set property **IsBodyHtml** to true.

```
public static void sendEmail(string emailbody)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("kamal.enest@gmail.com", "kamalu960@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Exception";
            mailMessage.Body = emailbody;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml true;
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "kamal.enest@gmail.com",
                Password = "1011664123"
            };
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
```

To bold some text: "`<b>Your bold text</b>`"

To set color: `<font color='red'>color text</font>`

```
public static void log(Exception ex)
        {
            StringBuilder sbEMessage = new StringBuilder();
            DateTime mydatetime1 = DateTime.Now;
            sbEMessage.Append("<table>");
            sbEMessage.Append("<tr><td>");
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Message" + Environment.NewLine );
            sbEMessage.Append("</td> <td>");
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("</td></tr>");
            sbEMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Date and Time" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(mydatetime1 + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Source" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.Source + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Hresult" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.HResult + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Stack trace" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine+Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception Data" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.Data + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Exception target site" + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("Inner Exception");
            sbEMessage.Append(ex.InnerException + Environment.NewLine);
            sbEMessage.Append("</table>");
            sendEmail(sbEMessage.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: i need to place exception property and exception value into different divs linked with their own style is it possible ?

Comment: yes... you should use table formatting. Updated the answer. Applied for first property Exception Message.